# How can I dynamically set the height of the horizontal scroll viewr?

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I want to set the `height` of the `horizontal scroll View` from my code. How is it possible?

....

Comment: You set layout scrollbar width and height?

Comment: yes exactly i want to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 HorizontalScrollView hv;

 hv = new HorizontalScrollView(this);
 hv.setMinimumHeight(intMinHeight);
```

try this: